# Jenkins Pipelines periodic build not sending email notification due to empty list of recipients

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, email-ext

We've set up a nightly build using a simple pipeline job that runs periodically every day and but the developers are not getting email notifications for it.

We're using the `emailext` [plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/email-ext/) for sending those emails and [Kubernetes agents](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) as nodes.

The job is started by a timer because it's a periodic build, making it run the following pipeline configuration (you can ignore the agent's container definition as it's not relevant, IMO):

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    kubernetes {
      yaml """
metadata:
  labels:
    some-label: some-label-value
spec:
  containers:
    - name: agent
      image: python:3.7
      command:
        - cat
      tty: true
"""
    }
  }
  options {
    timestamps()
  }
  stages {
    stage('SCM') {
      steps {
        checkout(
          changelog: false,
          poll: false,
          scm: [$class                           : 'GitSCM',
                userRemoteConfigs                : [[credentialsId: 'Git SSH Key', url: 'git@bitbucket.org:company/repository.git']]],
                branches                         : [[name: 'master']],
                doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                extensions                       : [[$class   : 'CloneOption',
                                                     depth    : 1,
                                                     noTags   : false,
                                                     reference: '',
                                                     shallow  : true],
                                                    [$class: 'PruneStaleBranch'],
                                                    [$class: 'GitLFSPull'],
                                                    [$class             : 'SubmoduleOption',
                                                     disableSubmodules  : false,
                                                     parentCredentials  : true,
                                                     recursiveSubmodules: true,
                                                     reference          : '',
                                                     trackingSubmodules : false]],
                submoduleCfg                     : []
        )
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        container('agent') {
          echo '-> install tox'
          sh 'pip install tox'

          sh 'python --version'
          sh 'pip --version'
        }
      }
    }
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        container('agent') {
          sh 'tox -c ./tox.ini'
        }
        post {
          always {
            echo '-> collecting artifacts'
            archiveArtifacts allowEmptyArchive: true, artifacts: '*.txt'

            echo '-> collecting test results'
            junit allowEmptyResults: true, testResults: 'output/pytest.xml'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  post {
    changed {
      emailext(
        subject: '$DEFAULT_SUBJECT',
        body: '$DEFAULT_CONTENT',
        recipientProviders: [culprits(),
                             developers(),
                             requestor(),
                             brokenBuildSuspects(),
                             brokenTestsSuspects(),
                             upstreamDevelopers()]
      )
    }
  }
}
```

The above does work when there is a manual start of the job (the starting developer gets the relevant email), however, when the job is triggered from periodic build (cron) - the recipients' list is always empty:

> An attempt to send an e-mail to an empty list of recipients, ignored.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to obtain the committers using git:

```
// Get all commits from the latest merge in an array 
def gitCommits = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log --merges -1 --format=%p').trim().split(' ')

// Get committer emails:
def emails = ""
gitCommits.each {
 emails = emails + sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git --no-pager show -s --format=%ae ${it}').trim() + ","
}
echo "${emails}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously all the recipient providers return empty list.

- `requestor()` returns empty list because there is no requestor
- `upstreamDevelopers()` returns empty list because there is no
  upstream build

Check the [source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/tree/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/emailext/plugins/recipients)  to figure out why the `culprits()`, `developers()`, `brokenBuildSuspects()` and `brokenTestsSuspects()` return empty list.